# PHP Timer-Repeat easier method

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$input = array("quote1", "quote2", "quote3", "quote4", "quote5");<br>
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);<br>
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]];
```

I need the code to do that, display the "quote", wait 10 seconds, then create another random quote to replace the last one. How would I do this? I have looked into finding system times and comparing them but I'm sure there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sleep()` functionality:

```
sleep(10);
```

That will sleep for 10 seconds.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that as with previous languages I have worked with, Sleep will completely pause the script. I'm presuming it doesn't in php. Thankyou!

Comment: Ok it stops the webpage from loading. How will I keep the page loading but also start a timer?